# Como reduzir a quantidade de If's em um redirecionamento simultâneo?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma função chamada redirectToNextPage que faz o seguinte: Pega o valor da URL da página anterior e, após três segundos, à redireciona para a próxima página, utilizando-se de um IF para cada URL, com uma exceção, porque a página inicial pode começar sem o parâmetro final que configurei através do queryParams.

Eu estou pegando a URL da página interior dentro do construtor da classe:

```
this.history = document.referrer
/// O document.referrer existe porque ele está redirecionando para essa página através de um link.
```

Eis a função :

```
redirectToNextPage() {
        if (this.history === 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html' || this.history === 'https://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=1') {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=2'
            }, 3000);
        }
        if (this.history === 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=2') {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=3'
            }, 3000);
        }
        if (this.history === 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=3') {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=4'
            }, 3000);
        }
```

Bom, a função segue assim até o 'quiz.html?quiz=10'. Porém, decidi não colocar toda a função aqui para não ficar gigante para vocês não se entediarem.

Resumindo. O que eu quero é trocar o final da URL, acrescentando um número a mais em seu final, a cada vez que for redirecionado para a página em específico.

O que eu tentei:

```
let historyArray = this.history.split('')
let takeLastNumber = historyArray.pop()
console.log(historyArray)
console.log(historyArray.join())

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            console.log('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=' + i)   
        }
```

Eu tentei transformar a string para array, retirar o último elemento dela - que é o número - e depois traze-la para um array de um único índice, que seria o link inteiro menos o último número. Porém, não estou conseguindo. Porque está retornando assim no console e não entendo o porquê:

> h,t,t,p,:,/,/,1,2,7,.,0,.,0,.,1,:,5,5,0,0,/,r,e,d,i,r,e,c,t,.,h,t,m,l,?,r,e,d,i,r,e,c,t,=,1

Bom, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso resolver isso de uma maneira mais simples. Eu ainda sou iniciante em programação e quero evitar essas más práticas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o que muda na URL são só os parâmetro de *querystring*, no seu exemplo "quiz", pode extrair os parâmetros e pegar o valor de "quiz" e somar 1, que é basicamente o faz nos vários `if`.

Tem muitas maneiras de fazer isso, uma mais simples, que funciona bem em navegadores mais modernos é usar [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Essa api faz o parse os parâmetros de uma URL, e permite usar um método `get` para pegar um valor, assim por exemplo:

```
var urlParameters = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html').searchParams;
var quizParameter = urlParameters.get("quiz");
```

Se retornar `null`, o parâmetro de *querystring* não existe na url, senão o valor é retornado, então para o seu exemplo poderia fazer um `if` para a condição null, e depois apenas somar 1 ao valor de "quiz", assim por exemplo:

```js
// testes:
console.log(obterProximaURL('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html'));
console.log(obterProximaURL('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=9'));
console.log(obterProximaURL('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=5'));
console.log(obterProximaURL('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=2'));
console.log(obterProximaURL('http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=batatas'));
console.log(obterProximaURL('http://algumoutrolink.com'));


function obterProximaURL(url) {
   var urlBase = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html';
   // verifica se a url passada inicial com o template da "urlBase"   
   if (url.startsWith(urlBase)) {
      // valor inicial, caso não tenha o parâmetro "quiz"
      var quizNum = 1;
      // usando a API, pega os paramentros da query
      var urlParameters = new URL(url).searchParams;
      // obtém o parâmetro "quiz"
      var quizParameter = urlParameters.get('quiz');
      
      // se o parametro de quiz está presente, soma 1
      if (quizParameter != null) {
         quizNum = Number(quizParameter) + 1
      } 
      // retorna a nova URL. Se quizNum for NaN (não é um número), retorna apenas a URL
      return isNaN(quizNum)
             ? urlBase 
             : urlBase + '?quiz=' + quizNum;
      
   } else {
     // aqui trata caso a url não seja a esperada
     return "invalido";
   }
}
```

No seu código é só usar pegar a URL retornada e setar no `window.location.href`

Comment: Talvez seja interessante fazer verificação para o caso `NaN` também.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe bem observado, adicionei a resposta obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa, por se tratar de um padrão que claramente se repete, seria utilizar Regex, pois dessa forma você consegue tornar a busca mais dinâmica.

```js
function redirection(link) {
  // Constrói o padrão que será utilizado na busca
  let pattern = /http:\/\/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.1:\d*\/quiz\.html(?:\?quiz=)?(\d*)?/i;
  // Realiza a busca no texto passado, retornando um array
  let grupos = link.match(pattern); // pattern => this.history

  if (grupos) {        
    let quiz = grupos[1] || 1;
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Enviado", link);
      let result = `http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html${ '?quiz='+ Number(++quiz) }`; 
      console.log("Retorno", result);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    console.log("Invalido");
  }  
}


// Testando
let links = [
  'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html',
  'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=1',
  'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=2',
  'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=3',
  'http://127.0.0.1:5500/quiz.html?quiz=10',
  'http://google.com'
];

links.forEach(l => redirection(l));
```

Outra forma de diminuir a quantidade de código que você escreve e assim diminuir o tamanho da sua função, é fazer o uso das novas features incluídas desde o ES6.